# How to test errors with Chai?

Tags: node.js, express, testing, mocha.js, chai

I am testing an api route that fetches an user. It works well. Now, I want to test if the route throws an error with the right message if I fetch an user that doesn't exist. The test claims to be positive, but I know it's not because I can't console.log the result nor the error in the `.end()` callback. here is the test and the route:

```js
require("dotenv").config();
import chai from "chai";
import chaiHttp from "chai-http";
import connectToDatabase from "../database/connection";
import { app } from "../index";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

chai.use(chaiHttp);
const api = chai.request(app);

before((done) => {
  connectToDatabase().then(() => done());
});

const token = jwt.sign(
  { _id: "123", locale: "en" },
  process.env.JWT_TOKEN_KEY,
  {
    expiresIn: "14d",
  }
);

describe("GET /user/:id", () => {
  it("return user information", () => {
    api
      .get("/user/607183db2020190b510bd9a5")
      .set("Cookie", `mycookie=${token};`)
      .end((err, res) => {
        chai.expect(res).to.have.status(200);
        chai.expect(res.body.user._id).to.equal("607183db2020190b510bd9a5");
      });
  });
  it("throws an error if the user doesn't exist", () => {
    api
      .get("/user/abc")
      .set("Cookie", `mycookie=${token};`)
      .end((err, res) => {
        console.log("res failed ok", res, "eeror", err); // this line never shows up
        chai.expect(err).to.throw("error.unknown");
      });
  });
});



// the route:
const getUser = async (
  req: GetUser,
  res: IResponse
): Promise<IResponse> => {
  try {
    const user = await UserControler.findUserById(req.params.id);
    return res.status(200).json({ user });
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error("error.unknown");
  }
};

export default getUser;
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

As described here(Caveat section) https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-http/, you need to use done when using end() function.

> Because the end function is passed a callback, assertions are run
> asynchronously. Therefore, a mechanism must be used to notify the
> testing framework that the  callback has completed. Otherwise, the
> test will pass before the assertions are  checked.

This causes your test to wait until done() is called. The end() function runs after your request is done. Passing a done parameter makes mocha wait until done() is called or timeout exceeds. If you don't use it, test succeeds without waiting the response.

so you should do this in your test(Note the change in the first test, too):

```js
describe("GET /user/:id", () => {
  it("return user information", (done) => {
    api
      .get("/user/607183db2020190b510bd9a5")
      .set("Cookie", `mycookie=${token};`)
      .end((err, res) => {
        chai.expect(res).to.have.status(200);
        chai.expect(res.body.user._id).to.equal("607183db2020190b510bd9a5");
        done(); // here
      });
  });
  it("throws an error if the user doesn't exist", (done) => {
    api
      .get("/user/abc")
      .set("Cookie", `mycookie=${token};`)
      .end((err, res) => {
        console.log("res failed ok", res, "eeror", err); // this line never shows up
        chai.expect(err).to.throw("error.unknown");
        done(); // and here 
      });
  });
});
```

Also using arrow functions for test functions is not the best practice. Use function(){ instead. Check this for the reason https://mochajs.org/#arrow-functions